# select to update with distinct mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
ID, initials, surname, company, active
1, p, abc, com1, 0
2, p, abc, com1, 0
3, c, acb, com1, 0
4, c, def, com1, 0
5, c, def, com1, 0
```

Now I want to update the duplicate combination of "initials, surname, company" to the status 1, resulting in the following:

```
ID, initials, surname, company, active
1, p, abc, com1, 0
2, p, abc, com1, 1
3, c, acb, com1, 0
4, c, def, com1, 0
5, c, def, com1, 1
```

The select is working:

```
SELECT DISTINCT initials, surname, company
FROM table
```

I tried this, but isn't working:

```
UPDATE table
SET active = 1
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT DISTINCT initials, surname, company)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UPDATE table AS t
  JOIN table AS tt
    ON t.initials = tt.initials
     AND t.surname = tt.surname
     AND t.company = tt.company
     AND t.id > tt.id
SET t.active = 1;
```

That is, for each row, update it if there exists another row with a lower id, with the same initials, surname, and company.

Here's an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e46b/1) for it.

Comment: getting this error #1093 - You can't specify target table 't' for update in FROM clause

Comment: thanks your fast reply but know am getting the following error: #1054 - Unknown column 't.initials' in 'where clause'

Comment: Is there any way to do this in a case where there is no primary key column?