# ODBC update single instance of duplicate row

Tags: sql, database, sql-update, odbc, duplicates

I'm working on a program that uses ODBC to read/write from databases of all types and I'm having trouble coming up with a solution for a problem where it is possible to have duplicate rows in the database but we only want to update one instance.

So for example, say the user connected to some ODBC database that has the following table:

```
first_name|last_name
--------------------
person    |man
person    |man
triangle  |man
```

In our application all three of these rows would appear in the UI and you can edit each one individually. The problem is that the database does not have a primary key column that our app knows about and we're not allowed to add anything to the database that the user doesn't add themselves so we can't just add a primary key column since it might break their database. Since there's no primary key column, when doing an `UPDATE`, the only way to know which row to update is to do a `WHERE` clause that compares the value of every column in the row. So something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET first_name = something WHERE first_name = person AND last_name = man;
```

This won't work because it will update all of the rows that have the matching first and last name and we want it to only update one of them. It doesn't matter which one gets updated so that should simplify things, hopefully.

I did find [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986038/select-to-update-with-distinct-mysql) that seems like it might be promising, but I'm unsure of how to modify it to work with a database that doesn't have a primary key column.

I'm currently using SQLite to test the queries so any solutions posted should be in that language if possible. I'll convert it to work with ODBC later once I confirm it works.

Answer (score 0):

Using ODBC against an unknown database engine you can probably only do this using a read/write cursor and a positioned update. This way you can update a single row even if other identical rows exist. Note that it is not certain that the ODBC driver for each database engine will support this type of updates, or even updates at all to tables without a unique index.

Comment: hmm I haven't done anything that fancy with cursors so I'll have to look into how to do what you describe before I know if it will work. At least it's something to start with.